# C# Regex for retrieving capital string in quotation mark

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Given a string, I want to retrieve a string that is in between the quotation marks, and that is fully capitalized.

For example, if a string of

> oqr"awr"q q"ASRQ" asd "qIKQWIR"

has been entered, the regex would only evaluate "ASRQ" as matching string.

What is the best way to approach this?

Edit: Forgot to mention the string takes a numeric input as well I.E: "IO8917AS" is a valid input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: If you *actually* want "one or more characters, and none of the characters is a lower-case letter" then you probably want:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\"\\P{Ll}+\"");
```

That will then allow digits as well... and punctuation. If you want to allow digits and upper case letters but nothing else, you can use:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\"[\\p{Lu}\\d]+\"");
```

Or in verbatim string literal form (makes the quotes more confusing, but the backslashes less so):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"""[\p{Lu}\d]+""");
```

---

**Original answer** (before digits were required)

Sounds like you just want (within the pattern)

```
 "[A-Z]*"
```

So something like:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\"[A-Z]*\"");
```

Or for full Unicode support, use the `Lu` Unicode character category:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\"\\p{Lu}*\"");
```

EDIT: As noted, if you don't want to match an *empty* string in quotes (which is still "a string where everything is upper case") then use `+` instead of `*`, e.g.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\"\\p{Lu}+\");
```

Short but complete example of finding and displaying the first match:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{    
    public static void Main()
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("\"\\p{Lu}+\"");
        string text = "oqr\"awr\"q q\"ASRQ\" asd \"qIKQWIR\"";

        Match match = regex.Match(text);
        Console.WriteLine(match.Success); // True
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);   // "ASRQ"
    }    
}
```

Comment: I think it should be + rather than * as you don't want to match empty quotes.

Comment: The above regex doesn't seem to work when I tried it in my code and in http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx

Comment: @SokwhanHuh: "doesn't seem to work" is pretty vague. I'll give a complete example of it working in my answer, but in future please be more specific.

Comment: First off, Regex regex = new Regex("\"[\\p{Lu}]+\");  results in a compiler error. I'm assuming you forgot to add another "

Comment: But even when I try Regex regex = new Regex("\"[\\p{Lu}]+\""); on my sample input, for instance "IAQWRQW" or "9KRQ24", Regex doesn't catch either of the string

Comment: @SokwhanHuh: Well in the second case you've got digits in there. You never said anything about wanting to support digits. I assumed you only cared about letters. Your first input works though - I've just tried it with the program in my answer. (And yes, I'd missed off a trailing double-quote, but that's obviously easily fixed... and I've already done so.)

Comment: Jon Skeet doesn't use `@"quotes"`? O.o (;

Comment: @Qtax: I would normally, but as we *also* want double-quotes in there, I figured I'd just use a regular string literal. Double-quotes get pretty confusing in verbatim string literals.

Comment: More answers should be as pro as this on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:
    "\"[A-Z]+\""

The outermost quotes are not part of the regex, they delimit a C# string.

This requires at least one uppercase character between quotes and works for the English language.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

`[\w]*"([A-Z0-9]+)"`